# Difference between jQuery form slider, script slider?

Tags: jquery

I am interested in using a jQuery slider for an input on my HTML form.

In certain [examples](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/forms/slider/), I see it invoked as an input like so:

```
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider-0" value="25" min="0" max="100"  />
```

However in other [examples](http://jqueryui.com/slider/), I see it invoked like this:

```
<head>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider"></div>
</body>
```

- What is the functional difference between these two snippets? Does one grant greater customization than the other (e.g. can I customize the background of the slider using the first code)?
- If I want to use the second one in a form, do I need a ``hidden field"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="range"/>` is an HTML5 input type, so it will only be supported by modern browsers (for a list of supported browsers see [this link](http://caniuse.com/input-range)). On older browsers, a range input will appear as a text input. More about the range type can be found on the MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

If you need to support older browsers (like IE 9 or below, which you probably will), you will need to use jQuery UI's slider or another library. These libraries use javascript to create a slider, but it is not the same as the native HTML `range` slider.

You can find the docs for the jQuery UI slider [here](http://jqueryui.com/slider/).

Comment: Did you see the link I provided with `<input type="range"/>`? It is in the jQuery documentation, I'm not sure why it's HTML5?

Comment: @user1850672 Later in that example they explain how to initialize the `slider` plugin by calling `$('input').slider();`. There isn't a way to initialize a jQuery UI widget through markup, it will always be done in javascript. They used `type="range"` in the example probably because most people will use jQuery UI to polyfill, to add HTML5 features for browsers that don't support it.

Comment: @user1850672 "The framework will find all input elements with a type="range" and automatically enhance them into a slider with an accompanying input" The plugin only supports `type="range"` and uses the standard attributes from that element to build the plugin. But that doesn't mean that having a `range` input on your page will automatically become a jQuery widget, you'll still have to explicitly call the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the javascript code.  Exists diferent ways to implement this.

on the first  `<input type="range"....................>` you only need the jquery livrarias and then this work.

jquery library (oldest version):

```
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js
```

the slider you can customize too. the jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css have a style and if you wante to change , basically on your stylesheet select:

```
input[type=range]{background-color:black}
```

and so on..

hope you have understand this. In my opinion implement the input type with the jquery library